# Sort array (resultset) according to a predefined array

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sorting, resultset

I am fetching data from an SQL database given a list of primary keys; the data returned is not always in the same order and I need to re-order them to preserve the original array index.

For example :

```
var ids = [2, 12, 5, 3, 10];
var query = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_foo WHERE id IN (' + ids.join(',') + ')';

db.query(query, null, function (result) {

   console.log(result.rows);
   // [ { id: 2, ... },
   //   { id: 3, ... },
   //   { id: 5, ... },
   //   { id: 10, ... },
   //   { id: 12, ... } ]

});
```

**Note**: nevermind the SQL injection warnings, this is an example; KISS.

How would I preserve that order, or would I efficiently order the resultset in the given original one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unnest` the `ids` array along with an index into a set. Then `inner join` that set to the target table using the generated index to order. In this example `t` is the target table generated by `generate_series`. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/2486)

```
with t as (
    select id
    from generate_series(1, 20) s (id)
),
a as (
    select
        unnest(array[2, 12, 5, 3, 10]) as id,
        generate_series(1, array_length(array[2, 12, 5, 3, 10], 1)) as i
)
select t.*
from
    t
    inner join
    a using (id)
order by a.i
```

The above is a self contained example. In you code you will use the existent table in place of `t`. In javascript use `String.replace()` to pass the `ids` array so you don't have to mess with string building

```
var ids = [2, 12, 5, 3, 10];
var query = '\
    with a as ( \
        select \
            unnest(array[%ids]) as id, \
            generate_series(1, array_length(array[%ids], 1)) as i \
    ) \
    select t.* \
    from \
        t \
        inner join \
        a using (id) \
    order by a.i \
'.replace(%ids, ids);
```

Comment: @Yanick Updated with simplified real javascript code